# Does the Monaco Diff Editor have out-of-the-box functionality to fold sections of unchanged lines?

Tags: monaco-editor

I would like to use the Monaco Diff Editor in my own project and would like to permit the user to fold any large sections of unchanged lines out of view,  possibly allowing the user to choose how many lines of unchanged code should be visible before and after any changed code.
I expect I could do this by registering folding regions and providing folding ranges but cannot see how to extract the relevant line numbers/positions from the Diff Editor.

Comment: same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71777516/monaco-diff-editor-view-only-changed-lines-in-monaco-difference-editor-side-by

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monaco-diff-editor: View only changed lines in monaco difference editor side by side view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71777516/monaco-diff-editor-view-only-changed-lines-in-monaco-difference-editor-side-by)