# Monaco-diff-editor: View only changed lines in monaco difference editor side by side view

Tags: monaco-editor

In monaco code diff editor, complete content is shown in original and modified section for side by side view. Can anyone please help in a way to show only changed lines in code difference editor without unchanged contents in the diff editor.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for inline version?

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-diffeditor-inline-diff-example

key is setting `renderSideBySide` option to `true`

```js
var diffEditor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(containerEl, {
    // Render the diff inline
    renderSideBySide: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's `hideUnchangedRegions` option:

```js
const diffEditor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(
    document.getElementById("container"),
    {
        hideUnchangedRegions: {
            enabled: true
        },
    }
);
```

[image]

[Docs](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/docs.html#interfaces/editor.IStandaloneDiffEditorConstructionOptions.html#hideUnchangedRegions)

[Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.46.0#XQAAAALWAwAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw42mvNOPOwgjnLcE1gNZMIvC1kjulawfJoSG8NAcYyiTab0VK7GjCzNKLAdedmNn4Samk6VfAph_lLom7XbURBvRejh8ZFBvrzcES37Pu6uKHhYl4crPeFsQDgQ_Z7Jt66t6-H6vq_jYcjaABL3-eFOGlRG76jJVTJyGg38gpzfiSbOfqO6-4YsE4vPCl6_zI1wDRV6WbuQquFky6LUmQMV9haA4dPc5h5CE6aJgBPNtVvyfRXqUG93HYZeufEXZ-Y_bF4kzKR-woenR1Bqz_VmTz5XEFRZ-lzXLb8TtV58pPkBWKrwfKrBwRktxB1OTmUdtY3MdTWiHKdeI7yFA1h6EiTJgB5AEBqycZKKUkyZYlJEAk3__ZXmwP)